# Zf2 Form dependent on userId

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity

I want to create a dropdown unique to the users, and found a way to do that, but its not ok with the client.

here is what i`ve done:

```
 public function __construct($name = null, EntityManager $em = null, $userId = null)
 {

    parent::__construct($name);
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    [...]
 $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'religionId',
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',

        'options' => array(
            'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
            'target_class' => 'Religions\Entity\Religions',
            'property' => 'name',
            'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'is_method' => true,
            'find_method' => array(
                'name' => 'findBy',
                'params' => array(
                    'criteria' => array('reUserId' => $userId),
                    'orderBy' => array('name' => 'ASC'),
                ),
            ),


        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,

        )
    ));


}
```

This worked, as i was sending the variable reuserId when initializing the form, using `$this->identity()`

The client wants to inject the user entity and select from there....

Searched stackoverflow and google, but was not able to find anything...any help please? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'inject' anything in ZF2 you will need to use the ServiceManager and create service factories.

It is therefore important to ensure that you are always creating the form via the ServiceManager.

In a controller for instance:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyModule\Form\FooForm');
```

Then you would need to 'inject' the user buy creating a factory class or closure.

**Module.php**

```
 public function getFormElementConfig() {
    return array(
      'factories' => array(
        'MyModule\Form\FooForm' => function($fem) {

            $serviceManager = $fem->getServiceLocator();
            $entityManager  = $serviceManager->get('objectmanager'); // Doctrine object manager

            // Load the user
            // Example is the zfcUser authentication service, however replace
            // this with whatever you use to maintain the users id

            $user = $serviceManager->get('zfcuser_auth_service')->getIdentity();

            // Inject the user entity into the form constructor
            $form = new FooForm($user); 

            return $form;
        }, 
      ),
    );
}
```

With that said I think you might need to think about the form dependencies. It seems to me that you do not *depend* on the user entity - but rather the user's id should be used in a database query that reduces the list of 'Religions'.

You could execute this query *and then* pass the result (The religion collection) to the form in the same way my example shows how to for the user entity - This would then mean you could use a 'normal' `Zend\Form\Element\Select` rather than the `ObjectSelect` - meaning no need to inject the `ObjectManager` etc.